# How do I only load one tab into memory at a time in Android?

Tags: android, memory-management, android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar

I'm creating an application with a `CustomPagerAdapter` that can be controlled by `ActionBar` tabs or horizontal swipe. When you select a tab, a `fragment` corresponding to that tab is displayed on the screen. When the app is created and when any tab is selected, the adjacent tabs, fragments are loaded into memory. I do not want this to happen. I would like it so that when a tab is selected only that selected tab's `fragment` is loaded into memory. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: The code I'm currently having trouble with is as follows:

```
public class fragA extende Fragment
{
    private VideoView videoViewA;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_A, container, false);

        videoViewA = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoViewA);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(final boolean isVisibleToUser)
    {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)
        if (isVisibleToUser)
        {
            videoViewA.setVideoURI(LINK);
            videoViewA.start();
        }
        else
        {
            videoViewA.stopPlayback();
        }
    }
}
```

The error I'm receiving is at the videoViewA.setVideoURI(LINK); line. Mind you, the link is actually there, but for privacy reasons I cannot post it.

Edit 2: It's ajava.lang.NullPointerException.

Edit 3: Sorry, but I'm doing this all the hard way. The code now reflects what I have actually written.

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't want this to happen?

Comment: The fragments in my tabs contain streaming videos and when a tab is selected, it causes anywhere from 2 to 3 videos to play at a time. When you have a tab selected, the adjacent tabs' fragments do not get paused or stopped, so the video will continue to play even though the fragment is not visible at the time.

Comment: You can pause the video when a certain fragment goes to background using its onPause() callback method, and then resume the video (if necessary) using the fragment's onResume() method.

Comment: When you have a tab selected, the adjacent tabs' fragments do not get paused or stopped. That solution will not work. Edit: Solution, not method, to avoid any confusion

Comment: You could just load the videos once the fragment becomes visible. Would that be suitable for you?

Comment: Yes, but as far as I'm aware, a fragment that is loaded when its tab is selected is still considered "visible" even if its adjacent tab's fragment is the actual visible one.

Answer (score 1):

Try loading your videos within setUserVisbleHint(), which gets fired by the FragmentPageAdapter upon showing the fragment.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint(boolean)

If that doesn't work for you, you can also try to do check onHiddenChanged(boolean hidden).
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onHiddenChanged(boolean)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will attempt to implement this and report back on its success.

Comment: I'm sorry, but after reviewing the setUserVisibleHint() documentation, I'm unsure of where to place it in my code or how to implement it. Does the method for it go into each individual fragment's class? Or does it go in my PagerAdapter class?

Comment: It's a fragment method that you can override in your fragment to receive the notification when it is shown. But notice that it is called automatically by the ViewPager, and not by the system itself

Comment: This seems to have worked in theory, but I am receiving NullPointerException errors from the VideoView inside the if-else loop I've created within the setUserVisibleHint method. I'll have to figure something out for that.

Comment: that seems to be a problem with the instantiation of the views. Just inflate your views normally in onCreateView and use setUserVisibleHint to load the video

Comment: Yes, that's what I was doing and that was causing the error.

Comment: If you edit your question and include the code causing problems I might be able to help

Comment: I assume you're getting a `NullPointerException`? Try to move the `videoViewA = (VideoView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoViewA);` to `onCreateView()`

Comment: Yes, I am getting that. And I accidentally put that there while writing my code in. It doesn't look like that in my actual code. Unfortunately, I can't copy and paste at the moment, so I'm doing things the hard way. Let me update it for you.

Comment: And your `videoViewA` is not null? Can you debug your code to see if it is properly instantiated?

Comment: Debug returned nothing

Comment: What does "Debug returned nothing" mean? Anyway, `setUserVisibleHint()` might be called once **before** `onCreateView()` is called. So put the following check in `setUserVisibleHint()` after `super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser)`: `if(videoViewA == null) return;`

Comment: When I hit the debug button in IntelliJ, nothing happens. It just compiles.

Also, I added your code: if(videoViewA == null) { return; } and the app does not crash, so it appears as if VideoViewA is actually null.

Comment: In order to debug the app, you have to set break points so you can see the state of certain variables and so on. If the answer helped you, please mark it as correct

Comment: Your responses helped me out. It can be tough for a new programmer out there! Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry, we all started some day. But again, please mark the answer as correct as described here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work